# Jade/Pug - appending to a class name

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Hello I have a unique id in an object and I want to append it to a class name. I am trying to do something like the following but it isn't working:

myJadeFile:

```
.googleChartContainer-#{attendanceAnalytics.uid}
```

myRoute.js:

```
res.render('./edu/school_dashboard_elementary', { attendanceAnalytics:attendanceChart });
```

I suppose I could create a class name in my route and send it as a variable with something like:

```
var className = '.googleChartContainer-attendanceChart.uid}';
res.render('./edu/school_dashboard_elementary', { attendanceAnalytics:attendanceChart, attendanceClassName:className });
```

and then in the jade file:

```
#{attendanceClassName} //- output is .googleChartContainer-someUid?
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get the first approach to work correctly, or if there is another preferred way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices. You can do it the JavaScript way with a string, like:

```
div(id=attendanceAnalytics.uid, class='googleChartContainer-' + attendanceAnalytics.uid)
```

or you create an JavaScript object containing keys and values to use them with the typical jade attribute `div&attribute(object)`, like this:

```
- var attr = {"id": attendanceAnalytics.uid, "class": 'googleChartContainer-' + attendanceAnalytics.uid}
div&attribute(attr)
```

Take a look into the JadeLang Docs, [chapter attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/).